# HTML5 video tag Firefox and jQuery controls Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, controls, html5-video

Don't find why the controls of my video tag doesn't work on firefox when i put the jquery.min.js file link on my page...
Do you have an idea ?

when the jquery file link is remove it's work on all browser but i need to use jquery for magnific-popup so can't be remove.

the code look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><% if (pageId != 'index') { %><%= pageTitle %> - <% } %><%= siteName %></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="canonical" href="<%= siteRootUrl %>" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/magnific-popup.css">
</head>
<body class="page-<%= pageId %>">
<video class="videos" controls="true" poster="./images/poster_inu.jpg" data-description="video1">
<source src="./images/inu.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="./images/inu.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="./images/inu.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check once your firefox version, it may be issue with html5 tag support

Comment: And what does the code look like when you include jquery? It really shouldn't affect it unless maybe your html is somehow malformed, or if you had other code running that needed jquery and is some how manipulating the video

Comment: what has jQuery got to do with your pure html5? how are you putting the jquery file link in the page? regular script tag? should not impact on the shown HTML at all

Comment: @RahulMeshram i test on Firefox 55.0.2 Mac
i test on localhost server and use gulp...

Comment: @PatrickEvans i use jquery for the magnific popup but for now i delete the gallery to solve the controls video problem.

Comment: @JaromandaX i update the code below